# get time in utc 2015-03-19T10:57:40.174Z format

Tags: php

I am trying to get time in 2015-03-19T10:57:40.174Z format but its not working for me

I have tried these-

1.

```
echo date('Y-M-DTHHM:SS.MMMZ');
```

2.

```
date_default_timezone_set('utc');
$datetime = new DateTime(); 
$str = $datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
echo $str;


output-2015-03-19T17:27:46+0530
```

3.

```
date_default_timezone_set();
print date('c');

  output-2015-03-19T17:33:52+05:30
```

but i need exact format(2015-03-19T10:57:40.174Z). how can i do that ?

please help.

Comment: Have you looked at the actual format codes used in the [date()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function? `echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u\Z');`

Comment: Or a more fancy `$dt = new DateTime(); echo sprintf(
    "%s%03d%s",
    $dt->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s."),
    floor($dt->format("u")/1000),
    "Z"
);`

Comment: Thanks [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) but its giving me 000 in milisecond everytime like- 2015-03-19T18:06:40.000Z

Comment: That depends whether your platform supports milliseconds times... PHP can't magically fill that in with an accurate value if the platform doesn't handle it; and it's only available in DateTime->format(), not with date()

Comment: [Mark](http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) thanks for help. i also want to know that how to subtract 4 hour and 30 minute from that time ?

Comment: `$dt->sub(new DateInterval('PT4H30M'));` to actually subtract 4hrs 30 minutes from the time; but if you want to adjust for timezone, then you should use the appropriate timezone setting, e.g. `$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));`